# Alternative word for playgoers' behavior

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a word for playgoers' behavior when hissing and booing the villain?

Comment: Alternatives, yes, but *hissing and booing* is the traditional terminology for what goes on at a [panto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantomime).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crowd as a whole, or members of it, could be *razzing* or *heckling*.

Some people in the crowd might be a little more obnoxious than others and engage in *badgering* or *taunting*, although those are generally more appropriate for a one-on-one situation.

Comment: thank you all, heeckling is the very woord, i was worried that it wouldn't be abusive enough...but it seems that it is.

Answer (score 4):

You can use *jeer*, *catcall*, *heckle*, or *hoot*.